# WordPress can't access permalinks settings after migration

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

I am (trying) migrating my WordPress page. I did copy the directory, change the mysql settings and change the `site_url` + `home` in `wp-options`.

Next step is to change the permalink so i get a fresh one on my server. But I cant get in the settings. Everything in the wp-admin works fine, but that option. It just shows me the front end. Just like i have opened blank page from my template. Most of the pages in the *front-end* website work.

Comment: Are you not able to see permalinks in settings?

Comment: @AhmedGinani I see it, but when I click, it goes to a blank template page (aka. the theme index.php fallback)

Comment: you need to delete the .htaccess file and then save the permalink , also check the site permission for files and folders

Comment: @AhmedGinani I can't access the page for the permalink, how am i supposed to save it?

Comment: Follow this :http://www.scott-benton.com/fixing-the-wordpress-permalink-blank-page-issue/

Comment: @AhmedGinani worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad to help :)